# Run Java Project From Linux Cmd

Tags: java, linux, shell, javac

I've written a java program and I'm trying to run it from cmd both in Windows and Linux.
I first compiled and then run it , and it worked just fine on Windows.
The problem comes up when I'm trying to do the same thing on Linux. The commands I've used on Linux are :

```
javac -cp aspose-cells.jar:aspose-words.jar:aspose-slides.jar ConvertToPdf.java


java -cp aspose-cells.jar:aspose-words.jar:aspose-slides.jar ConvertToPdf
```

The first command , which starts with `javac`, works just fine and outputs the `ConvertToPdf.class` file. The problem comes up after running the second one , which outputs the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ConvertToPdf
```

I'd like to know what am I doing wrong , and I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the current directory `.` to the classpath:

```
java -cp aspose-cells.jar:aspose-words.jar:aspose-slides.jar:. ConvertToPdf
```

Answer (score 0):

your working directory is not included in class path.
do this :

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<your-jars>:.
```

it should work !!!